# How to stream response body in Quarkus with Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, quarkus, coroutine

**Goal**

Build a service that streams a zip file built on the fly. The zip file contains files downloaded via HTTP. Files are big enough to don't fit into RAM. Using filesystem should be avoided since it's unnecessary.

**Problems**

JSX-RS defines StreamingResponse and seems to be the answer. However, it's not supported by the Quarkus Reactive. It just returns `ZipResource$ZipStreamingOutput@50a05849` as a response body.

Using Multi (from Mutiny) as a returning result does not allow bridging it with Kotlin coroutines, because coroutines require calling them from suspend function. And if the method is marked with `suspend` then it just returns `io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.multi.builders.EmitterBasedMulti@24ac00e7` as a function body.
Example code:

```kotlin
@GET
@Produces("application/zip")
suspend fun download(): Multi<String> {
    return flow { emit("hello") }.asMulti()
}
```

Also even if it worked, I don't see any option to specify response headers.

**Criteria**

- Non-blocking streaming, so that concurrency is not limited by the number of threads
- Kotlin coroutines are preferable since it's native for the language rather than framework-specific

**Context**

- Kotlin 1.5.30
- Quarkus 2.2.2.Final

Here is a simplified thread-blocking implementation, which I want to implement in a non-thread-blocking (reactive) way.

```kotlin
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.net.URL
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream
import javax.ws.rs.GET
import javax.ws.rs.Path
import javax.ws.rs.Produces
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response
import javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput

data class Entry(val url: String, val name: String)

@Path("/zip")
class ZipResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("application/zip")
    fun download(): Response? {
        val entries = listOf(
            Entry("http://link-to-a-source-file1", "file1.txt"),
            Entry("http://link-to-a-source-file2", "file2.txt"),
        )
        val contentDisposition = """attachment; filename="test.zip""""
        return Response.ok(ZipStreamingOutput(entries)).header("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition).build()
    }

    class ZipStreamingOutput(private val entries: List<Entry>) : StreamingOutput {
        @Throws(IOException::class, WebApplicationException::class)
        override fun write(output: OutputStream) {
            val zipOut = ZipOutputStream(output)
            for (entry in entries) {
                zipOut.putNextEntry(ZipEntry(entry.name))
                val downloadStream = URL(entry.url).openStream()
                downloadStream.transferTo(zipOut)
                downloadStream.close()
            }
            zipOut.close()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting use case. Currently we provide have an easy way to do this. Please open an issue in the Quarkus Github repository so we can consider adding it.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: @costa I saw someone created a Github issue and fixed it if I'm not mistaken. But I had to switch to micronaut which supports kotlin flows as a method return value.